# selecting a node in a treeview, on select of a node in a separate treeview

Tags: c#, treeview

So basically i have 2 treeviews running next to each other, one shows a list of drugs that someone might be on the next shows the latests prescription date for that drug.

what i am trying to achieve is someway of when the user selects a drug in treeview A, it highlights that drugs latest prescribe date in treeview B, however my attempts havent been successfull yet and so i turn to you guys for help :)

this is the code i have tried in in the after select event of treeviewA

```
 int selected = mainTree.SelectedNode.Index;
 secondTree.SelectedNode = secondTree.Nodes[selected];
```

which did nothing basically..

i am open to ideas, if i am honest i would prefer to in someway have both the drug name and last prescribe date in the same treeview, this would make it much tidier, but i am not sure if u can have 2 trees next to each other

Comment: Is this WPF or Winforms?

Comment: I don't get it.  Why isn't the 2nd treeview a label instead?

Comment: because of the dynamic number of items, plus a patient may have both active + inactive drugs, which all may or may not have a history of prescribing, coupled with the nice feature of using treeview, is if for example the patient has lets say 100 active meds, and 20 inactive, the user can collapse the active drugs bringing the inactive to the top. if you can understand that explanation your a genius :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you can't see any nodes selected is probably because by default the TreeView control will hide the current selection when the control has lost focus. If you add `secondTree.HideSelection = false;` to your code, you'll be able to see the effect that you want.

However, saying that I can't help but think that there may be a better way. Can't you use a label in place of the second TreeView? Clicking a drug in the first TreeView would then just show the last prescribed date in the Label?